# Return column value based on results of WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I want to select records based on a WHERE clause, and include a column in the result that tells why each record passed the WHERE clause's filters.

Something like

```
SELECT name, location, networth, reason
FROM aTable
WHERE location = "France" OR networth > "100"
```

which might return

```
name|location|networth|reason --reason is the part I need help with
-----------------------------
Joe |France  |0       |Location
Jeff|England |500     |Net worth
Tim |France  |500     |Net worth and location
```

Is there a cleaner way to set "reason" than repeating the WHERE clause's predicate inside the SELECT clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with concatenated conditions.  It makes it much easier as you add more.  And, in most databases, I would use a subquery.  Using `concat()` to combine reasons:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             concat((case when location = 'France' then 'France; ' else '' end),
                    (case when network > 100 then 'net worth; ' else '' end)
                   ) as reasons
      from atable a
     ) a
where reasons <> '';
```

There are various nuances to this query, depending on your database (string concatenation might differ, for instance).  But this allows you to define the reasons only once, and not have to repeat them in both the `where` clause and the `case` statement.

Comment: This solution is pretty neat, but it requires accepting a change to the desired outcome:  instead of being able to produce "Location and net worth", this would produce "France; net worth;".   Also, if this were used as part of a large query/dataset, I'd test carefully for performance, because I suspect any indexes on the SARGs will be ignored.

Comment: @TabAlleman . . . (1) Yes, the desired outcome is a little different.  This is the format I when when faced with this issue.  (2) Indexes probably won't be used effectively for `or` conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is with a CASE statement in the SELECT clause that repeats the conditions in your WHERE clause.

```
SELECT NAME,
    location,
    networth,
    CASE 
        WHEN location = "France"
            AND networth > "100"
            THEN "Location and Net Worth"
        WHEN location = "France"
            THEN "Location"
        WHEN networth > "100"
            THEN "Net Worth"
        END AS reason
FROM aTable
WHERE location = "France"
    OR networth > "100"
```

Comment: almost +1.  You should start the CASE statement with the "Net Worth and location" case.

Comment: I missed that one! I've added it now.

Comment: And... I like Gordon's answer below. It adds a level of complexity, but it satisifies OP's request of only having to change the conditions in one spot. I'm leaving mine up since it's an answer that solves the need to put the 'reasons' in the results.